# OR-Tools: Partial Solution ignored due to "unknown rate is too large"

Tags: python, vehicle-routing, or-tools, warm-start

With `SetHint()` from the OR-tools linear solver I am trying to pass a feasible solution to my problem. But I receive the following warning:

`WARNING: ignore partial solution (0) because unknown rate is too large (0.862233 > 0.85)`

What is the unknown rate and how can I reduce it?

I firstly thought, "unknown rate" refers to the proportion of variables that I provide a value for. But even when providing a value for all variables, I receive the warning above.

Background: I am dealing with a VRP and its split delivery generalization. First, I calculate a solution without splits passing it with `SetHint(variables, values)` to the generalized model. I have done this before with Gurobi (warm start), but wanted to try the same with the OR-Tools SCIP solver. I am working with Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
SetSolverSpecificParametersAsString("heuristics/completesol/maxunknownrate = 0.9")
```

References:

- [SCIP params](https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/PARAMETERS.php)
- [SetSolverSpecificParametersAsString usage](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/linear_solver/scip_interface.cc#L1028)

Comment: This is it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the warning comes from SCIP. So check the documentation there.

Comment: This may be better suited as a comment (as is).

Comment: I think this answer is likely to be a downvote magnet.  As pointed out, it should be a comment since it doesn't really answer the question and simply directs the OP to "the documentation."

Comment: OK. How do you reply when the warning comes from a dependency?